# Return file descriptor from Bash function

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptor

I have this Bash function now, which is "hardcoded" to write a JSON message to a file descriptor:

```
ql_connect(){
   port_file="$HOME/.quicklock/server-port.json"

   my_str=$(cat "$port_file");
   typeset -i my_num="${my_str:-"1"}"

    exec 3<>"/dev/tcp/localhost/$my_num"  # persistent file descriptor

    exit_code=$?

    if [[ ${exit_code} -ne 0 ]]; then
      echo "quicklock: could not connect.";
      return 1;
    fi

    echo "{\"init\":true,\"quicklock\":true,\"pid\":${BASH_PID},\"cwd\":\"$(pwd)\"}"  >&3
    echo "" >&3
    ql_node_receiver <&3 | ql_conditional_release &

}
```

I'd like to make it generic - instead of hardcoding what I write to the file descriptor, I'd like to return it to the caller; is that possible in Bash?

Something like this instead:

```
ql_connect(){
   port_file="$HOME/.quicklock/server-port.json"

   my_str=$(cat "$port_file");
   typeset -i my_num="${my_str:-"1"}"

    exec 3<>"/dev/tcp/localhost/$my_num"  # persistent file descriptor

    exit_code=$?

    if [[ ${exit_code} -ne 0 ]]; then
      echo "quicklock: could not connect.";
      return 1;
    fi

  return &3; # return reference

}
```

but obviously that's not going to work - how can this be done?

Comment: It's just a number. You don't need any kind of special "reference" type.

Comment: yeah I was thinking that, humma

Comment: (that said, exit status should be used to determine whether a function succeeded, not to return a result).

Comment: can you add an answer explaining why / how etc

Comment: Which version of bash, specifically? 4.1 added automatic FD allocation; it'd be nice.

Comment: yeah that's why I think I need to use another methodology then return the status and mixing that with other meaning

Comment: bash 3/4 I have to support both

Comment: Ugh. Bash 3 makes this much messier.

Comment: tell Apple to have MacOS to come with Bash 4 out of the box :(

Comment: Not gonna happen for licensing reasons (Apple is rabidly anti-GPLv3), but they've got ksh93 -- why aren't you using that? Most of bash's new/shiny features are stolen from ksh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to return any kind of special reference type. Assuming bash 4.1 or newer, you can let the shell automatically assign an available FD number, and then do an indirect assignment to store that in a caller-specified variable:

```
# accept variable name to store FD in as an argument
ql_connect() {
  local _qlfd _fd_var=$1
  exec {_qlfd}<>"/dev/tcp/localhost/$(<~/.quicklock/server-port)" || return
  printf -v "$_fd_var" %s "$_qlfd"
}

if ql_connect qlfd; then
  echo "hello" >&$qlfd
fi
```

---

With bash 3, by contrast, it's better to let the user explicitly assign a FD:

```
ql_connect() {
  local eval_str
  printf -v eval_str \
    'exec %q<>%q\n' "$fd_num" "/dev/tcp/localhost/$(<~/.quicklock/server-port)"
  eval "$eval_str"
}
if ql_connect 3; then
  echo "hello" >&3
fi
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to listen for a disconnect event? if the server goes down, or what not? that would be good to know and would help for context.

Comment: You can of course tests whether reads and writes fail. Otherwise, I'd suggest using a shim like `socat`, such that you can test whether it's still running. Though if you need to support bash 3, you can't get the PID of a process substitution, so it's *still* unnecessarily complicated to get the corner cases right.

Comment: ...also, with socat, you can get your script invoked with stdin and stdout connected directly to the socket. That tends to make things a lot easier in general.

Comment: if I run the `ql_connect` routine twice, it hangs on the second time, I need to keep track of whether it's connected or not